# How do you show all of the rotating values on a WheelPicker in swiftUI and not just the selected value?

Tags: date, datepicker, swiftui

I have a standard date wheeldatepicker, but want to show all of the spinning values and not just the value it settles on and selects.  Do you know how to do this?

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
       let year = formatter.string(from: date)
                     
       return formatter
}

 var body: some View {
     VStack(alignment: .bottom){
        DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, in:closedRange, 
              displayedComponents: .date)
                        .scaleEffect(0.8)
                        .labelsHidden()
                        .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                        .padding(.bottom, -20)
                    
                    Text(" \(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")

   }
}
```

Comment: Did you declare $date as a State?

Comment: Not clear what do you mean, would you add some details?